# iOS side scrolling view with export options and social integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am writing an app in Xcode for iPhone (exclusively) that will deal with a Photos app like photo library. Within the iOS 7's Photos app, in an Album, when you hit 'Select' on the top right, highlight an image, and hit the 'Export' looking button on the bottom left, the app displays a side scrolling view with copy/assign to contact/ etc and other app integration options.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl4JF.jpg

Does anyone know what this is or how one could implement this in another application? Does Apple have any documentation on how they do this? I have noticed it in a few other iOS 7 apps like Safari for example.

Any code, suggestions, or links would be very helpful.

Comment: If any of the answers were helpful you might consider up voting. If the answer led to a resolution of your issue you may consider clicking the checkmark so that others will find the solution. Selecting answers will encourage others to contribute to your questions in the future. You also may want to look into the docs and the class header files a bit further as this is a basic question. Searching SO before posting the question might also have revealed existing answers. Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs, that is a UIActivityViewController. You can find sample code by searching SO for other questions on that topic.

Comment: AWESOME!Thanks, very appropriately named

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code of `UIActivityViewController`.

```
NSString *string = ...;
NSURL *URL = ...;

UIActivityViewController *activityViewController =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[string, URL]
                                applicationActivities:nil];
[navigationController presentViewController:activityViewController
                                  animated:YES
                                completion:^{
// ...
}];
```

By using the same you will have the below UI.

[image]